# How can I make my code find solution while working at specific coordination?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I made the code that solves maze recursively. **0** means path, **1** means wall. You can go through wall as long as `abilcnt > 0`. I think the problem lies here:

```c
else if (abilcnt != 0 && maze[i][j] != 0) {
    abilcnt--;
    if (findpath(i, j - 1) || findpath(i + 1, j) || findpath(i, j + 1) || findpath(i - 1, j)) {
        maze[i][j] = 2;
        return 1;
    }
    abilcnt++;
    printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

I made my code to try going through the wall at every single coordination. If value of the cnt is 0 and if there is no way to go, I tried to recover it by abilcnt++.

But when maze provided like:

```
0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 0
```

It doesn't go through the wall at (1, 3), and value of the abilcnt seems to be 1 at (1,3) but 0 at (1,1).

I don't know why my code doesn't work. PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: OT: Your check for valid `i` and `j` should be the **first** code in the function. Currently you access out of bounds in the very first line.

Comment: OT: When all your blocks contain a `return`, you don't need the `else`

Comment: "... value of the abilcnt seems to be 1 at (1,1) but 0 at (2,1)." No that is not correct. If abilcnt is 1 in (1, 1), the code **will** goto (2, 1) and have abilcnt equal 1.

Answer (score 2):

When you do backtracking, you probe the adjacent cells, but first, you set the properties of your current cell as if the probed directions led to a valid path. If probing succeeds, just report success ( `return 1`) and leave everything as it is. If not, clean up after yourself by resetting the cell to its initial state. You must do that, so that you don't revisit already visted cells, which are marked as **2**.

```
if (maze[i][j] == 0) {    
    maze[i][j] = 2;

    if (findpath(i, j + 1)) return 1;
    if (findpath(i - 1, j)) return 1;
    if (findpath(i + 1, j)) return 1;
    if (findpath(i, j - 1)) return 1;

    maze[i][j] = 0;
}
```

(You do that more or less in your code, but state **3** in your code means "never visit me again", which is useful only when `avilcnt` is zero at the beginning. The cell may be visited via various paths, so the algorithm must be able to visit again later, possibly by having passed through a wall somewhere.)

The current count of `avilcnt` belongs to the overall maze state, so the same applies here: Set the successful state and probe. If probing is successful, leave everything as it is; if not, clean up.

```
if (maze[i][j] == 1 && abilcnt > 0) {
    maze[i][j] = 2;
    abilcnt--;

    if (findpath(i, j + 1)) return 1;
    if (findpath(i - 1, j)) return 1;
    if (findpath(i + 1, j)) return 1;
    if (findpath(i, j - 1)) return 1;

    abilcnt++;
    maze[i][j] = 1;
}
```

As "4386427" already mentioned in the comments, checking the coordinates should be the first thing in your function, so that `maze[i][j]` won't access the array out of bounds. Putting everything together:

```
int findpath(int i, int j)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= mazesize || j >= mazesize) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (i == mazesize - 1 && j == mazesize - 1) {  
        maze[i][j] = 2;
        return 1;
    }  

    if (maze[i][j] == 0) {    
        maze[i][j] = 2;

        if (findpath(i, j + 1)) return 1;
        if (findpath(i - 1, j)) return 1;
        if (findpath(i + 1, j)) return 1;
        if (findpath(i, j - 1)) return 1;

        maze[i][j] = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    if (maze[i][j] == 1 && abilcnt > 0) {
        maze[i][j] = 2;
        abilcnt--;

        if (findpath(i, j + 1)) return 1;
        if (findpath(i - 1, j)) return 1;
        if (findpath(i + 1, j)) return 1;
        if (findpath(i, j - 1)) return 1;

        abilcnt++;
        maze[i][j] = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```